# c* - understanding 'select distinct' usage

Tags: cassandra

I have a **Cassandra** table with 5 'key' columns and a value. Im wondering if there is a way - using just the one table - to scan for combinations of key columns. Im fine with 'pinning' one to find values of the next but haven't found the right syntax for C* to accomplish anything like this.

What I've tried:

- using `PRIMARY KEY(a, b, c, d, e)`

  - `select distinct a from <table name>` - this works and give distinct 'a'

Ok. Cool.

- using `PRIMARY KEY(a, b, c, d, e)`

  - `select distinct b from table where a = <some known value>` - this doesn't work and reports `WHERE clause only supports restriction by partition key`

Fine. I'll be more specific.

- using `PRIMARY KEY((a, b, c), d, e)`

  - `select distinct a from <table name>` - doesn't work and reports `Partition key parts: resource must be restricted as other parts are`

Ok.. even *more* specific

- using `PRIMARY KEY((a, b, c), d, e)`

  - `select distinct c from <table name> where a = <known value> and b = <another known value>` - this reports `WHERE clause only supports restriction by partition key`

So it's clear that I don't know how to use the **distinct** keyword in C*.

Question:

- is it possible to find distinct *combinations* of partition keys?
- is there another method to achieve this? Use lookup tables for all the subsets?

(Using cassandra 3.9 on CentOS 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinct keyword only works if it's on all the (CQL3) partition key columns.

So in your case the following query worked because in this case the partition key is a.

`select distinct a from <table name>`

in the second case `select distinct b` did not work because b is not the partition key.

if you are using `PRIMARY KEY((a, b, c), d, e)`

you have to use distinct on all the partition keys. in this case you have composite partition key a,b,c.

So in your distinct list you have to specify all three.

you can read the patch here https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12598894/4536.txt

Look for the method **validateDistinctSelection** and you can see various conditions which are used to allow the distinct selection.

Comment: Well rats. Looks like "amber waves of lookup tables" in my future.